# Regex php get mysql insert values

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to take the values from a sql file with lots of inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO "Messages" VALUES(7662,1,7333,'#foxy.giulia/$marcobonetti7;f966f2547124846f','marcobonetti7','marcobonetti7',NULL,X'6DF3228A75EEF69EB124C51BD0CA6EB7F3C35B33DC8062F479B60AC80442C21A','marcobonetti7',1386795144,61,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Domani durante il giorno sei a casa?',NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL,3,4,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,1198575,3063654961,309438692,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Complete SQL file is provided in  [this pastebin](http://pastie.org/pastes/8734218/text).

I have made this far `preg_match_all('/insert into "([a-zA-Z]+)" values\((.*)[\);]{0}/isu')`, but it doesn't take in account `\r\n` from `Values(.*)` and it doesn't detect it.

I need the values and the table name from a `.sql` file. The values can be only an entire string.

Comment: Why don't you include \r\n in your regex?

Comment: Why don't you just import the table into your database and then export what you want?

Comment: Do you need the values as array or as single string?

Comment: because its actual an sqlite file and Im tring to convert to mysql.

Comment: For that, take a look at [this blog post](http://paulasmuth.com/blog/migrate_sqlite_to_mysql/) for migrating a SQLite dump to a MySQL database.

Comment: I have already  done a part of this... but its not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will match the table name and the whole list of values as string:

```
preg_match_all('/insert into "([a-zA-Z]+)" values\((.*?)\);/isu', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

After that you could split the values with:

```
foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
    $matches[$key][2] = explode(',', $match[2]);
}
```